# Get public facebook pages feed via graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get my hands dirty with code and start working on some small projects, so I decided to work on a facebook scraper that pulls feed from a public page and sends results via email.

when I try the URL : https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/posts?access_token=APP_TOKEN, I'm getting " This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.

What am I missing?!

Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

In order to pull the feed with the Graph API, you need to:

- Manage the Page, and use a Page Token of that Page to get the feed
- or apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version4.0#page-public-content-access), if you do not manage/own the Page